# Problem with Ruby Gem Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am having trouble using the Ruby Gem paperclip. I followed the instructions in the ReadMe but I cannot seem to get it to actually load my images. Here is my edit form:

```
<% form_for :user, @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :expertise %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :expertise, :class => "expertise" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :occupation %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :occupation %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :city %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :state %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
```

<%end%>

Yet when I try to save I keep getting this error: No route matches "/users/4/edit"

What is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that there's no /users/4/edit route. What does your config/routes.rb look like? If there's a line like:

```
resources :users
```

Then, try changing that first line to:

```
form_for @user
```

Instead of:

```
form_for :user, @user
```

Also, I don't see a file_field in there anywhere so I don't think this question is about Paperclip?